# Size-1 only error when using contour() to plot a multivaried function. Not sure why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Am attempting to plot a complicated two variable function using contour. I am receiving a "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" error on my contour function call.

'''

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import (contour,plot,grid,xlabel,ylabel,show,legend,subplot,figure,suptitle)
import math 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sympy.solvers import solveset
from sympy import Symbol

V = 3.78 #m^3
CA0 = 5000.0 #mol/m3
CB0 = 0.0 
Keq0 = 9.0 #at 350K
Ea = 15000.0*4.184 #j/mol
R = 8.314 #j/mol/K
DHrx = -25000.0*4.184 #j/mol
T1 = 350.0 #K
kT1 = .4/V/CA0/(.6**2-(.4**2/Keq0))
dT = 1.0
dX = 1/310

T,X = np.meshgrid(np.arange(290,600,dT),np.arange(0,1,dX))

contour(

    T,X,
    X-V*kT1*math.exp((Ea/R)*((1/T1)-(1/T)))*((1-X)**2-(X**2/(Keq0*math.exp(DHrx/R*((1/T1)-(1/T)))))),[0]
)

show()

'''
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. **Goal is to plot the function of T,X equal to zero**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error in numpy:TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442225/error-in-numpytypeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `np.exp` on arrays not `math.exp`. `np.exp` takes the exponential of every element in an array, whereas `math.exp` only works on single numbers, eg. `int` or `float`.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import (contour,plot,grid,xlabel,ylabel,show,legend,subplot,figure,suptitle)
import math 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sympy.solvers import solveset
from sympy import Symbol

V = 3.78 #m^3
CA0 = 5000.0 #mol/m3
CB0 = 0.0 
Keq0 = 9.0 #at 350K
Ea = 15000.0*4.184 #j/mol
R = 8.314 #j/mol/K
DHrx = -25000.0*4.184 #j/mol
T1 = 350.0 #K
kT1 = .4/V/CA0/(.6**2-(.4**2/Keq0))
dT = 1.0
dX = 1/310

T,X = np.meshgrid(np.arange(290,600,dT),np.arange(0,1,dX))

contour(

    T,X,
    X-V*kT1*np.exp((Ea/R)*((1/T1)-(1/T)))*((1-X)**2-(X**2/(Keq0*np.exp(DHrx/R*((1/T1)-(1/T)))))),[0]
)

show()
```

[image: figure]